# Safe to use pot that has a scratch inside?

Tags: food-safety, kitchen-safety

My pot has a scratch in it, is it still safe to use? I attached a picture of the scratch[image]

Comment: It's difficult to tell from the picture. Is it a teflon coated pan? Is this the inside or outside of the pan?

Comment: I think it's non stick. It's the inside of the pot.

Comment: It looks like there are several patches of discoloration inside the indent - do you know if these are also damage, or can you say why you think the scratch may be unsafe while you are not concerned about the larger patches?

Comment: I use worse on a regular basis

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this is the inside of a non-stick pan, on the side near where the handle is riveted (scratched rivet at the right of the picture).

It doesn't look like it's peeling from the scratches.  So the amount of coating getting into the food would be miniscule. Even the if it did peel, the result would be more unpleasant than dangerous ([paper on the use of PTFE as an inert bulking agent for food](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26810925)); the main component of a Teflon non-stick coating is PTFE.